# Get the total cost in ruby based on item name, value and class object array

Tags: ruby

I have the following array

```
class_object = [Foo.new(item: 'apples', value: 100), Foo.new(item: 'bananas', value: 100)]
```

I then have a function:

```
initialize(item_name, quantity)
  # get price
end
```

I want to say: search the class_object for a name that matches `item_name`, then take the quantity and multiply it by the value to then give me an expected out put of, assuming the item_name is apples and the quantity is 6:

```
apples 600
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself? You can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to find an item in an Array based on a condition. With that you should be able to locate the desired `Foo` and then just do the multiplication.

Comment: The problem is I wouldn't know what to try ...

Comment: Do you need `Foo`? The easiest way to accomplish this would be to store items and values in a hash: `fruits = {'apples' => 100, 'bananas' => 100}`. To get the price for six apples you'd just do, `fruits['apples'] * 6`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def class_object 
  [Foo.new(item: 'apples', value: 100), Foo.new(item: 'bananas', value: 100)]
end

def initialize(item_name, quantity)
  value = class_object.find {|o| o.item == item_name}.value
  "#{item_name} #{value * quantity}"
end
```